# Can I force NFS clients to map all user/groups to "nobody" on shared files?

Tags: linux, permissions, network-shares, nfs

I have just successfully set up a NFS client and server. I have just been surprised by NFS's willingness to handle UIDs unchanged between the client and server.

For example, suppose these user names/ids exist on the server:

```
root 0
admin 1
alice 100
```

And these on the client:

```
root 0
bob 1
admin 2
alice 123
```

In the current situation, if `admin` on the server creates a file in the shared directory, the client sees it as owned by `bob`. **This is an obvious security problem** because `admin` might falsely believe that permissions of `544` protect the file from unauthorised writes.

Moreover, `alice` might get the false impression that she can correctly share files with herself and keep the file permissions sane.

Thing is, if the *client* creates a new file in the share, the server sees it as owned by `nobody`. *This is what I want in both directions.* That is, the client should see `nobody` as owning the file even if `admin` created it on the server -- in my situation, the act of sharing strips meaningful ownership because there is no user ID correspondence across the machines.

In short, I want all NFS clients to be told that `nobody` owns all the shared files, regardless of whether the server knows better. Also, all writes from clients will be owned by `nobody` and marked as such on the server.

Can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need the `all_squash` parameter in your exports file, together with `anonuid=xxx,anongid=xxx` you can even chose which user to assign the files to.

Even Windows users can be integrated via the `force user` and similar directives on Samba.

Comment: Half works. Now `root` on the client creates files as `nobody` but files owned by `root` on the server do not appear to be owned by `nobody` on the client.

Comment: You need to chown them once - from then on, everything stays as "nobody". Of course you may not touch the files directly on the host - mount locally via NFS as well.

Comment: But when the server adds new files to the share, I want them to be served as nobody without having to intercept each subsequent write and chown it.

Comment: Just self-mount on the server! This way everything is translated as desired.

Comment: @jbarlow You are welcome to complete and un-mislead it. If not, I suggest man exports` (e.g. on https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports if it is not on the system)